# Cucumber in IntelliJ: Shouldn't selecting a test item display its data?

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

Suppose I am running a cucumber scenario inside IntelliJ 2019.2 .

All the tests passed successfully.
When I click the test item in the tree - should I see the test information?

I do see the scenario and feature information, but then I have to search the specific test info.

Some images for illustration:

[image]

However, for a specific test - no info:

[image]

Comment: By 'test information' you mean the logged info during the test? Do you have any logged information? Normally it's displayed in the test runner tab (Footer -> tab Run) when you click on the scenario's name (the line Scenario: create App Preconditions).

Comment: @MrCas Yes, but in the run tab I also see the complete log. I wonder if I can see the specific step log only?

Comment: Please file an a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with an example test or better a sample project for the feature.

Comment: Not sure if you could see the specific step log only. However you could implement a class StepRunListener which extends RunListener (import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener) and log information about the step name when the step starts/finish -> https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/Description.html#getMethodName()